# Automating the Creation of Geometric Shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, inkscape

How can I draw geometric shapes, or other regular shapes, such as a gear, using macros or scripts?  I'd like to experiment with creating games by combining elements, similar to geoDefense: http://www.criticalthoughtgames.com

Comment: Which software? The solutions will differ from app to app. Should your game create the shapes dynamically rather than creating the shapes in a graphic editing software beforehand? You can't create games with ia. Photoshop, maybe Flash would be better option? (…and in the last two cases, this question is probably quite off–topic for the site)

Comment: I have Photoshop, Gimp and InkScape on a Mac.  Anyone will do.  From the basic shapes, I'll try to compose other images.  Flash doesn't work on iPhone/iPad.

Comment: I should add that I recently bought Photoshop so I would like to learn it well.

Comment: What exactly do you need to script? If you merely need to *create* a shape, would saving a shape as a PSD be sufficient? You could consider it as a template and later save your edits as a new file.

Comment: Ugh, we're playing question with question.  I'm a programmer.  I'm very comfortable using scripts and macros so I'd like to leverage that where I can to describe a shape, or series of them.

Comment: I rather ask for clarifications than just vote to close. First, I tried to figure out which tool you're intending to use. Second, I tried to figure out whether your *problem* can be solved in other manners (contra answering the *question* you provided), as I haven't got too much of an experience with Photoshop scripting.  I know it can be scripted with AppleScript, VBScript and JavaScript. Adobe Developer Connection page might be one of the best places to start: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html I hope someone can provide a more thorough answer to your question.

Comment: Vote to close.  Looking for programming advice -- better off asking on [SO]

Comment: @Farray I'm looking for a turnkey solution in Photoshop, Gimp or Inkscape from a menu.  Short of that, the next best solution would be a script/plugin for one of these tools that works.  Sorry if it crosses the programming lines, but if I have to do it myself... well I will.  Prepping my Google Fu for an evening of Photoshop CS5 scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It sounds like you're looking for snippet code in Scheme.  This really isn't [the place to find that](http://www.stackoverflow.com/). That aside...*

---

### Simple Polygons (triangles, squares, pentagons, & so-on)

These shapes are the easiest.  All you need to do is find evenly distributed points along the circumference of a circle.  There is 1 point per side, so a triangle will have 3 points on a circumference, a square will have 4, etc.

The seemingly "scary" part is getting the circumference coordinates but it's actually pretty simple.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
GetEndPoint( startX, startY, radius, angle )
{
    endX = startX + ( radius * Sin( angle * PI ) )
    endY = startY + ( radius * -Cos( angle * PI ) )
    return endX, endY
}
```

Now that you have a simple way to find points, all you have to do is iterate your way around the circumference and draw a line from point to point.

```
poly( centerX, centerY, radius, sides )
{
    incrementAngle = 360 / sides

    currentAngle = 0
    while ( currentAngle < 360 )
    {
        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle
    }
}
```

If you combine these concepts with PhiLho's suggestion about creating SVGs, you can very easily script creation of a polygon.

`poly( x, y, 50, 5 )`
[image: pentagon svg]

### Stars

Stars are only slightly more complicated than polygons.  The process is the same, but you have 2 radii to deal with which means you'll have twice as many points.  Notice that you need to use a smaller incrementing angle and you're adjusting it for each radii on each loop.

```
star( centerX, centerY, radius1, radius2, points )
{
    incrementAngle = 180 / points

    currentAngle = 0
    while ( currentAngle < 360 )
    {
        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius1, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle

        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius2, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle
    }
}
```

Again with PhiLho's excellent SVG idea:

`star( x, y, 50, 20, 30 )`
[image: star svg]

### Gears

Once you've figured out stars, you can apply the same concept to gears.  You have 2 radii and you just have to alternate drawing 2 consecutive points on each circumference.

```
gear( centerX, centerY, radius1, radius2, teeth)
{
    incrementAngle = 90 / teeth

    currentAngle = 0
    while ( currentAngle < 360 )
    {
        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius1, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle

        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius1, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle

        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius2, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle

        coordinates = GetEndPoint( centerX, centerY, radius2, currentAngle )
        DrawCoordinates( coordinates )
        currentAngle += incrementAngle
    }
}
```

One more tip of the cap to PhiLho:

`gear( x, y, 50, 46, 24 )`
[image: gear svg]

Answer (score 3):

Please note this answer addresses both the question and the comments...

Some things just aren't easily scriptable. A gear isn't a "regular" shape. Basic shapes—squares, circles, and the like—are so simple to create in the apps you mention that a script isn't necessary unless you plan on doing some complex transformations with the shape afterwards. A gear, on the other hand, really isn't a scripted item in a graphics application; an image of a gear is made by hand, or a pre-existing image altered to suit particular needs, then exported to the required format per your project's spec and used accordingly during runtime.

You don't mention how far you are in planning your application, but I suggest you look at your project specs and start looking at how you intend to use the art in question, because your implementation will drive how and what you create in a graphics application if you create anything in Photoshop at all. Your framework of choice (per your example would most likely be Core Graphics or Cocos2D) may already have something to offer in terms of ready-made functions to create and manipulate simple to moderately-complex shapes.

Gears are common to games, not graphics applications. Graphics applications are more about providing the core tools needed to make any kind of gear imaginable. Games invariably require custom graphics that aren't easily scripted until you have a clear idea in mind of what you want to make, and even then, the workflow would still more than likely be similar to what @koiyu described.

Also, take into consideration that it may be (more than likely will be) faster to simply draw the gear by hand (or hire someone) than to find a programmatic way to do this.

Comment: Not automated but I found how to draw a gear in Inkscape: http://www.wikihow.com/Draw-Gears-in-Inkscape

Comment: I don't understand when you write that gears are not "regular shapes. What is your definition of "regular"? I made and saw programs drawing gears. One of the interests of such script would be to define the number of teeth, the size, etc.

Comment: @PhiLho: "regular" is, obviously, a subjective term. In my context for this question, which is largely driven by Adobe Illustrator, gears are not a part of the standard tool set or in the default plug-ins, at least for what I do. Creating gears automagically is something that has to be specially written. I've needed rounded rectangles a lot more than I have needed gears.

Comment: @Philip: Ah, so it was in the sense of "common", not in the sense of "with regularity in the form"... :-) Indeed, it is something that must be scripted, that's the point of the thread, no? ;-)

Comment: @PhiLho: Yes, this question is about scripts, but I don't know of any off the top of my head, and I'm not about to write one.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manuals?

Gimp can be scripted in Scheme (and some other languages like Lua). Inkscape can be scripted in Python, I think. Photoshop can be scripted in its own language (VBA?) too.

Beside, you can use any language to generate SVG files (assuming you learn the format...), and most of them (with the proper libraries) to generate bitmap images.

[Update] OK, I did the requested research... Two interesting Gimp scripts, one in Scheme, one in Python, coming with source code for further studying:
[Shape Paths](http://registry.gimp.org/node/59)
[Gimp Path Tools](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/)

They are not really simple... But the hard part, coding, is done so that lot of shapes can be done without even coding.

Comment: Your answer really doesn't offer anything concrete.  Can you provide a solution in Scheme, for example, to draw a geometric shape?  People come to sites like this to get answers that will save them time.

Comment: I don't see the value of giving a code snippet that applies only to a very specific case. Your question is about programming. That's something you must learn (programming, or if you know that already, the specific language & API).

Comment: I didn't even think about script-created SVGs.  That's an excellent suggestion...

Comment: Ugh. Personally, I would remove the "Read the manuals?" and "LMGTFY".  The point of these wiki sites is to gather the information and present it in a coherent, comprehensive and succinct way so that when the next person Googles "How do I ...", he gets an answer more quickly.  Many answers are already buried out there but this wiki site is often a better format.  All questions from trivial to hard should be here.Btw, the Shape Paths looks promising.  Downloading Gimp now to try the plugin.

Comment: OK for the LMGTFY, I usually don't use the formula, but I was a bit upset. ;-) I leave the "read the manuals" part, as this advice is often overlooked by people, as softwares are user friendly...

Comment: @M-x If you'd like to shape the direction that GD is going, please weigh in over at [meta](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).  As it stands right now, most of the SE sites tend to shy away from overly-trivial questions/answers and management has stated "we're not a snippet site".  Not that those answers can't find a home here, but it's not really what you should inherently expect to find.

Comment: A plugin is great.  Code helps some people, but it will have a limited audience, of course, but still useful.  I'm just trying to solicit good answers so the next person with my question, will find an answer here that helps.  Ideally, Gimp/Photoshop/Inkscape solutions are provided here and code solutions would be linked to StackOverFlow. eg.  Implementations in JavaScript.